# search pattern and print in same line

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a big .txt file in below format

```
  Pin name="AR_OP" status="f" 
      Pref x=997.6800 y=2327.0400 side=N width=0.0400 depth=0.3750 /
      Layer id=1 
--
  Pin name="AW_OP" status="f" 
      Pref x=997.6800 y=2327.0400 side=S width=0.0400 depth=0.3750 /
      Layer id=2
```

I want the output as below:

```
Pin name="AR_OP" side=N
Pin name="AW_OP" side=S
```

for each section I want to search **pin name** and corresponding to that pin name I want **side** in same line.
Can anyone help.

Comment: Define the context. From what/where this output comes from?

Comment: Are the individual records separated by the `--` indicated in your example, or by empty lines (or not at all, and each occurence of `Pin` serves as start indicator)?

Comment: If the input was originally from HTML or XML, then please post this as well.  Parsing the data from the original format is often safer, more convenient and generally better, especially if the original format was some structured document type rather than just plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all spaces by newlines, then pull out lines that are `Pin`, or that start with either `name=` or `side=`.  This gives us lines in groups of three.  Reformat each group of three lines into a single line with spaces as delimiters.

```bash
$ tr ' ' '\n' <file | grep -e '^Pin$' -e '^name=' -e '^side=' | paste -d ' ' - - -
Pin name="AR_OP" side=N
Pin name="AW_OP" side=S
```

This assumes that none of the values contains embedded spaces.

---

Assuming the document was originally some XML document like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Pin name="AR_OP" status="f">
    <Pref x="997.6800" y="2327.0400" side="N" width="0.0400" depth="0.3750"/>
    <Layer id="1"/>
  </Pin>
  <Pin name="AW_OP" status="f">
    <Pref x="997.6800" y="2327.0400" side="S" width="0.0400" depth="0.3750"/>
    <Layer id="2"/>
  </Pin>
</root>
```

Then the data would be better extracted from *this* with an XML-aware tool than from a post-processed variant thereof with text-processing tools.

For example,

```
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match  '//Pin' --output 'Pin' \
    --output ' name="' --value-of '@name'      --output '"' \
    --output ' side="' --value-of 'Pref/@side' --output '"' \
    -nl file
```

This uses `xmlstarlet` to find all the `Pin` nodes in the input document.  It then iterates over these, outputting their `name` attribute and the `Pref` subnode's `side` attribute in the requested format.

A similar approach [with `xq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), an XML parser wrapper around the well know `jq` JSON parser:

```bash
xq -r '.root.Pin | map("Pin name=\"\(."@name")\" side=\"\(.Pref."@side")\"")[]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

Works both for text file (*AS-IS*) and [html](/questions/tagged/html) or [xml](/questions/tagged/xml):

```bash
xidel -e '//Pin/concat(
    "Pin Name=&quot;", @name, "&quot; side=&quot;", ./Pref/@side, "&quot;"
)' file.html
```

##### Output

```
Pin Name="AR_OP" side="N"
Pin Name="AW_OP" side="S"
```

Comment: This work great if working with html files. If am I working with .txt file can I get a solution wrt awk.

Comment: The example you provided **IS HTML** (or `XML`). Post another question with text

Comment: Moreover, the commands works with your input AS-IS, even with the `---`

Answer (score 0):

If the block format in the file is the same. With `gawk`:

```bash
gawk '/^\s*Pin name=/ {NF=2; a=$0; getline; print a, $4}' file
```

In the GNU `sed` editor, we can emulate a selection by fields:

```bash
sed -E '/^\s*Pin name=/!d;N;s/\s*(\S+ \S+)(\s+\S+){5}.*/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of `side` always consists of at least one uppercase character:

```
awk '{
    if (match($0, /Pin name="[^"]+"/)) {
        printf "%s ", substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        next
    }
    if (match($0, /side=[A-Z]+/)) {
        printf "%s\n", substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    }
}' file
```

This outputs only the matched parts plus a space or newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (/^\s*(Pin name="[^"]*").*/) {
               $pin = $1;
               $_ = <>;
               if (/(side=.)/) {
                 $side = $1;
                 printf "%s %s\n", $pin, $side;
               }
             }' input.txt
Pin name="AR_OP" side=N
Pin name="AW_OP" side=S
```

In English:

If the current line matches `Pin name"[^"]*"` then extract it with a capture group (`$1`) and store it in variable `$pin`, then read the next line (`$_ = <>;`).  If it contains "side=." then extract that into variable `$side` and print both $pin and $side with a space between them.  All other input lines are ignored.

Here's another variant:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (/^\s*(Pin name="[^"]*").*/) {
               $pin=$1;
               ($side = <>) =~ s/^.*(side=.).*/\1/;
               printf "%s %s", $pin, $side if $side =~ /side=/
             }' input.txt 
Pin name="AR_OP" side=N
Pin name="AW_OP" side=S
```

In English:

If the current line matches "Pin name..." then extract it and save in variable $pin, then read the next line `($side = <>)` into variable `$side` and modify $side to delete everything but "side=." ( `=~ s/^.*(side=.).*/\1/;`), then print them both **if** `$side` contains `/side=/`.

---

BTW, that `($side = <>) =~ s/^.*(side=.).*/\1/;` line is an example of a useful perl idiom for assigning a variable and then immediately modifying it with a substitution operation (`s///`.  `tr///` works too).  It's the equivalent of two statements: `$side=<>` to read the next line into $side, then `$side =~ s/^.*(side=.).*/\1/;` to modify $side.

The parentheses around the assignment are important, otherwise the variable will contain either success/failure or a count of the substitution operation (but only if the right-hand-side of the `=` assignment is a modifiable variable - if it isn't, if it's something unmodifiable like a file handle then it's a syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 's{print s $4; s=0} $1=="Pin"{$3=""; s=$0}' file
Pin name="AR_OP" side=N
Pin name="AW_OP" side=S
```